# symfony phpunit

Tags: phpunit

Всем доброго времяни суток, хочу написать для своего учебного проектика тесты. Большая часть функциональности эта парсинг данных. Как это тестировать.. Покажите пример для ниже приведённой функции.. Они похожи, я думаю мне это сильно поможет..

```
public function getUri($content)
{
    $crawler = new Crawler($content, 'http');

    $result = $crawler
        ->filter( '#main > ul > li' )
        ->each( function (Crawler $node) {
            return $node->filter('a')->attr('href');
        });

    return $result;
}
```